# Is there a way to get the changed bytes between files via DropNet?

Tags: c#, api, dropbox, wrapper, dropnet

I am using the DropNet API to communicate with Dropbox.

I noticed the clients GetFile call has an overload which takes the start and end bytes of a file, essentially meaning we can grab a portion of it.

Is there a way to check via the DropNet api calls which bytes have changed between revisions?

What I mean by that is, let's say I downloaded revision 1 of a file. The file is now at revision 2. Using DropNet, how would I get the bytes that have changed so when I call the GetFile overload I only end up downloading the changed bytes, instead of downloading the entire file again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dropbox API itself doesn't offer a way to determine what bytes in particular have changed in a file, so unfortunately this won't be possible using the DropNet library. (We'll consider this a feature request for the Dropbox API though.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I figured there must be a way to do it if DropNet offers a start/end byte way to get files, and considering our users are using mobile we figured it might be a way to reduce the data they use when downloading files. I'm guessing DropNet has the start/end override then to allow you to download files in chunks, not for the purpose we were thinking.

Comment: That's correct, the Dropbox API supports Range Retrieval Requests so you can download specific pieces of files if you know what pieces you want, but the API doesn't have a way to tell you what pieces have changed.